# hello everyone, I have a problem with npm. npm install

Tags: firebase, npm, npm-install, firebase-tools

I have a problem with npm.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

After firebase login, I get "command not found" error. I uninstalled node js and reinstalled it still the same problem. I would be glad if you help.

```
firebase login
-bash: firebase: command not found
```

Comment: It looks like `firebase-tools` was not correctly installed. What output do you get after you run `npm install -g firebase-tools`?

Comment: It look correct installed, does not appear any problems

Comment: sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
Password:
/Users/macbook/.npm-global/bin/firebase -> /Users/macbook/.npm- global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
+ firebase-tools@7.3.0
updated 2 packages in 37.78s

Comment: Please include this information in your question, not (just) in comments. What type of system are you running these commands on? (just trying to help troubleshoot here, as I don't have an idea as to what's causing this at the moment)